# How to implement Google credentials from my iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have to inplement Google credentials from my iPhone application.

Can anyone suggest the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [gdata-objectivec-client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/). It supports, amongst many other things,:

***Google ClientLogin authentication***

Frank