# Is there any approach to login into the iphone app through Google credentials

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have one doubt that is, Is there any approach to login into the iPhone app through Google Credentials.

I have made one iphone application, Based on the login credentials, If exists in the server then I am taking user into the application.

Also If user uses or enters his Google credentials if exists then also i need to allow him into the application.

plese help me.
Thank you,
Madan Avulagadda.

Comment: As Frank suggested in this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746593/how-to-implement-google-credentials-from-my-iphone-application) you should have a look at http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

Answer (score 0):

OAuth should have what you need.

Read the [checked answer here about OAuth.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544388/openid-authentication-and-api-access)  Then go to the [UsingOAuthConsumer site](http://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer/wiki/UsingOAuthConsumer) and read about using OAuth with Objective-C.  You'll also need information from Google about [OAuth for Installed Applications](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuthForInstalledApps.html).  Looks like it will take a bit of work, but the info and some libraries are out there.